# Generating datasets with a certain probability

Tags: python, statistics, dataset, probability

Suppose I have 60% of red balls and 40% of blue balls. How can I generate 1000 datasets each containing 10 balls? (Python)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `([red] *6 + [blue]*4) * 1000`

Comment: @Sayse where is any probablity involved in your answer?

Comment: 1000 datasets of how many entries each dataset?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki "each containing 10 balls"

Comment: but then is not dataset. is one dataset with 1000 entries consisting of 10 balls

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki If he considers 10 balls a dataset, that is 1000 datasets.

Comment: @matszwecja - Where is any probability involved in the question?

Comment: @Sayse In the literal freakin title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use random.choices to pick items from a collection randomly, based on weights provided.

```
dataset = random.choices(
    population=['blue', 'red'],
    weights=[0.4, 0.6],
    k=10
)
```

Sample output:
`['red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red']`